# I am unable to fetch data from Impala in Azure Data Factory . Copy activity throughs query timeout exception

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using a copy activity which I have simple select query which retrieves data from Impala view and write into Azure SQl Db.

Unfortunately copy activity returning  timeout exception from source quqery.

I ran the same query in impala editor it tooks 10-15 mins to complete. How can i increase query time out in Azure Data Factory Copy activity or any other options to fix this issue.

Comment: Data Factory doesn't have the option to increase query timeout time for SQL database query. Your query takes a lone time. You should optimize the query or the database query performance firstly.

Comment: Hi @user15488631,hope you're doing well. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory doesn't have the option to increase query timeout time for SQL database query. Your query takes a lone time. There may be many reasons that caused the query timeout.

I would suggest you optimize the query performance in the Azure SQL database firstly. Then put the query in Data Factory source query option.

You could ref these documents:

1. [Query Performance Insight for Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use)
2. [Azure SQL Database Performance Tuning Options](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/03/azure/azure-sql-database-performance-tuning-options)

There are many ways and you can easily find them in searching.

HTH.